# Confused about t-contrasts, F-contrasts and the associated tests (t-test, ANOVA)

Tags: anova, t-test

What is the difference between a t-test and a contrast tested using a t-test?

When would an F-contrast be used instead of a regular t-contrast? Is the relationship between the two the same as between an ANOVA and a t-test?

Finally, is the answer to any of the above questions related to the fact that a "difference" contrast for a factor with N levels will have N-1 columns? (i.e., a difference contrast is only a vector (-1,1) for factors with 2 levels)

Comment: Just wondering if this question was perhaps not clear enough? Very much look forward to some thoughts/answers, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the question(s) could use some clarification, but here is an attempt at answering.

First you ask what the difference is between a t-test and a contrast tested using a t-test.  There are actually many different tests that can be called a t-test, this is one of the things that makes the question unclear.  Any time that you have a parameter estimate that is (approximately) normally distributed divided by a standard error (estimated standard deviation of the parameter estimate based on the same data) then the resulting test statistic is (approximately) distributed according to the t distribution and can be tested using a t-test.  This includes the 1 sample t-test, the paired t-test, the independent 2 sample t-test, test of a regression slope, etc.  Since a linear combination of normal estimates is also normal, this means that testing a single contrast falls into this category as well (the tests that I listed can be reformulated as tests on contrasts).

When comparing the t-tests and the F-tests you should understand that an F-statistic based on 1 df in the numerator is just the square of a t-statistic.  So there are many tests that could be performed using either a t-test or an F-test and you will achieve the exact same results.  The advantage of the t-test is that sometimes it is simpler and more directly interpretable and you can do one-sided tests with the t-test much more simply than the F-test.  The advantage of the F-test is that it can look at several tests/parameters/etc. simultaneously.  So just like you can compare 2 means with a t-test (or ANOVA), but need ANOVA to test more than 2 means; you can test a single contrast with a t-test (or an F-test), but need an F-test to simultaneously test more than 1 contrast and control the overall or family-wise type I error rate.

Comment: Thanks Greg, it's helpful to better understand how all these concepts relate to each other. I could be conceptualising this last question oddly as well, but why is it that a contrast checking the main effect of a 2-level factor, i.e. (-1,1), is a row-vector, while a contrast checking the main effect of a 3-level factor is a 2x3 matrix? For instance Statistica suggests, for such a case, a "simple" contrast, i.e. (1, 0, -1; 0, 1, -1) or a "difference" contrast, i.e. (-1, 1, 0; -1, -1, 2)? Does the answer to this question have to do with the F-test being, in a way, a generalisation of the t-test?

Comment: @wildetudor, yes you can think of it as the F being the generalization of the t.  The main effect of a 2 level factor can be a row vector, or think of it as a 1x2 matrix.  The number of columns is always the number of levels, and a complete test of the factor requires $k-1$ contrasts to fully constrain all the levels.

Comment: I see, but is it correct to say that the 1-column contrast that tests the 2-level factor is done with a t-test, while the 2-column contrast that tests the 3-level factor is done with an F-test?

Comment: @wildetudor, the 1 column for the 2 level could be done using either a t or an F (the F will just be the t squared).  The 3 level needs an F.  So any number of levels can be compared with the F, the t is a special case for when you only have 2 levels.